# Save method is not working for products

Tags: magento-1.9, products, save, methods

I want to resave all products programmatically. So I am trying to use the below code to achieve it. But the save method is not working in it. I have placed the code in the root directory of my Magento 1.9 installation. Can anyone kindly let me know how can I make it work?

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

// require magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

// execute on admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();


foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->getData('sku') . '<br/>';
    // save the product
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: How did you understand that product save is not working as you have not changed anything and save? Try to change some value of products and try save. If still not working then try to load the product and then save.

Comment: I have tested it by echoing and checking where exactly the loop is stopping. The for loop is traversing only once, displaying only one SKU and it is stopping at the save method. No changes are being done. I checked that too.

Comment: Can you load the product on loop once and try?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do changes in order to save something. If you don't change anything, then there is no need to `save()`.

This works pretty good:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($products as $product){
     $product->setData('sku', $sku);
     $product->save(); 
}
```

Comment: I am actually trying to save again because I am importing stocks programmatically. But once the stocks are imported and few products go out of stock, those products still show up in the front end. Only after I save those products from backend explicitly the product disappears from the front end. Hence I am trying to save all products programmatically once again after the stocks are imported.

Comment: Even now it is stopping at one iteration. It is working for just first product. It is saving that first product and the loop is not moving further for next iteration. I don't understand why it is happening.

Comment: You should try to reindex the product if it runs out of stock. Normally Mage does this on his own.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code :**

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

// require magento core
require_once 'app/Mage.php';

// execute on admin store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();


foreach($products as $product) {
    $name = 'xyz';
    $productLoad = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
    echo $productLoad->getData('sku') . '<br/>';
    $productLoad->setData('name',$name);
    // save the product
    $productLoad->save();
}
```

Comment: Does this changes the name of all the products in my store to 'xyz'?

Comment: yes but you an try only one product if working fine then you change all product data.